# What is a dot (.) supposed to do in MySQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out why when I enter a dot (.) into my search, it highlights every single character of the search results (it wraps each character in a `<span class="search-highlight"></span>`) and it's also only showing 3 tickets which is weird because all of them have at least one dot in them:

[image: screenshot]

The query that does the actual searching (along with the variables) is:

```
$q = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']);
$query = trim(strtoupper($q));
$query = htmlentities($query, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$construct = $is_employee==false ? "user='$userid' AND" : "";
$tickets_result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `subject`, `message`, `timestamp`, `user` FROM `tickets` WHERE $construct (upper(subject) LIKE '%".$query."%' OR upper(message) LIKE '%".$query."%')") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

And my `highlight` class:

```
class highlight
    {
        public $output_text;

        function __construct($text, $words) {
            $split_words = explode(" ", $words);
            foreach ($split_words as $word) {
                $text = preg_replace("|($word)|Ui",
                        "<span class=\"search-highlight\">$1</span>", 
                        $text);
            }
            $this->output_text = $text;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know why or how a simple dot (.) would cause this and is it possible to fix?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Sounds like the search may be working, but the highlighting is haywire.  ('.' is any character in regular expressions, wonder if there's a regular expression in the highlighting code somewhere?)  preg_replace() looks suspect.

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php to escape your query.
See http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php for more info

Comment: @Maz I already am using that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see where you used it above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just gotta add an alternative to escaped regular expression search here:

Perhaps what you want is a non-regex replace?

https://www.php.net/str_replace

> str_replace — Replace all occurrences of the search string with the
> replacement string

For an exact match, that makes the most sense to me...

Comment: Well, this worked the best because I don't have to worry about the regular expressions anymore and since I'm still using the `foreach` loop it seems like it works the same. But do you know what could be causing this when I enter "this is a test": http://screencast.com/t/D6gdkexso Really odd...

Comment: Yes, simple string search isn't tokenizing the words to match.  (doh!)  If you went back to regular expressions you could wrap your expression with word boundary '\b' on each side.

Comment: Oh. I've never heard of that. :/ So if I go back to regular expressions, which I _really don't want to do_, I can just add that and it'll work correctly and not mess up after like 4 words or whatever?

Comment: follow kolink's preg_quote advice first.  Then around the quoted string (call it $qword) do: "\b($qword)\b" instead of: "|($word)|Ui" (see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
Note: I agree performance will suffer with regex, but otherwise you'd have to write a custom str_replace() which looks for word boundaries.

Comment: I'm getting an error with that regex: `Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\wamp\www\config.php on line 188`

Comment: oh sorry, you still need the wrapper part: "|\b($qword)\b|Ui"  (normally it would be / ie: "/\b($qword)\b/" but apparently the other was working for you)

Answer (score 4):

It's the `preg_replace` that's "at fault" here. `.` is a wildcard character, so it matches anything.

You might want to run `preg_quote` on your input string before putting it in the regex.

Comment: I put `preg_quote` in the highlight class and it works. Thanks! There's one more small problem, I'm sure it has something to do with the regular expression, but when I enter `this is a test` it also highlights them all (it seems like more than 3 words it does that). Do you know if that would be a problem with the query or the regular expression?

Answer (score 2):

You are using preg_replace which is a regular expression search.

The . in regular expressions matches any character. Actually has nothing to do with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

`.` (dot) has a special meaning in regular expressions - it matches every character - and that's why your whole data is highlighted. You should use escape and search for `\.` instead of just a dot.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.preg-quote.php on user's input, coz preg_replace takes dot as expression part which matches every single character.